# Getting django record by foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following relationships:

```
class AMe(models.Model):
    Field1                  = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = Field1_CHOICES)
    Field2                  = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = Field2_CHOICES)

class MP(models.Model):
    MyAMeID                 = models.ForeignKey(AMe)
    Field1                  = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = Field1_CHOICES)
```

Now the issue is that I want to select the records in the MP by the foreign-key i.e. MyAme, but the FK is not the same as the primary key of AMe, so what is a foolproof way of selecting the record in MP? Should I use the queryset and filter option? Or is there a smarter way, more Django way of doing this that I have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `my_AMe_object.mp_set.all()` (Django automatically creates reverse relations for `ForeignKey` fields by concatenating the model's name - here `mp` - and `_set`, can be set directly by `related_name` field attribute), or `MP.objects.filter(MyAMeID=my_AMe_object)`.

Example usage of the reverse relation:

```
>>> from test_app.models import AMe, MP
>>> ame = AMe.objects.create()
>>> for _ in xrange(6):
...     MP.objects.create(MyAMeID=ame)
>>> ame.mp_set.all()
[<MP: MP object>, <MP: MP object>, <MP: MP object>, <MP: MP object>, <MP: MP object>, <MP: MP object>]
```

Note that `mp_set` returns a `QuerySet` object despite the number of results (similar to regular `Model.objects.all()` method).

Comment: Do I have to appened MyAMeID as this MyAMeID_id as it appears in the table?

Comment: If you are passing an instance of a model to `filter`, use the field's name. In this case that would be `MyAMeID`. If you are passing a primary key, use `MyAMeID_id` (django appends `_id` under the hood).

Comment: Hmm. I cannot seem to get either of these methods working. It should work, the filter method is the most familiar, but also the mp_set.all() is returning the following error:AMe' object has no attribute 'mp_set'

Comment: There might be something about your models that the snippet above did not include, can you include your whole file?

Comment: It's massive and I can't because of confidentiality :-( One issue could be the huge number of 'models.ManyToManyField' in mp.

Comment: Check out my edited answer, I've added example of the `mp_set.all()` method.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I get when looking at the mp object....MyMP.__and__(                       MyMP._prepare(
MyMP.__bool__(                      MyMP._raw_delete(
MyMP.__class__(                     MyMP._result_cache
MyMP.__contains__(                  MyMP._result_iter(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44650/discussion-between-kroolik-and-navonod)

Comment: Thanks, its important to note what is returned is a list essentially. So getting the object back is from a list if if only a single instance is done via .all()[0]